# Compass background mixin with variable argument

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Here is a very reduced test case of what I am trying to accomplish:

This works:

```
html
  $gradient: red, salmon
  +background(linear-gradient($gradient))
```

This does not work:

```
html
  $gradient: top, red, salmon
  +background(linear-gradient($gradient))
```

And it gives me this error: "`At least two color stops are required for a linear-gradient()`"

Yet, `$gradient: top, red 10%, salmon 10%` doesn't work. Nor does `$gradient: 35% 10%, red 10%, salmon 10%`. I need to be able to pass any valid CSS3 combination of the gradient syntax into the mixin, even multiple gradients.

`+background(linear-gradient(35% 10%, red 10%, salmon 10%))` works, so I assume it should with a variable placeholder as well.

How can I get `+background` to accept any valid CSS I pass it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Sass [Variable Arguments](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_arguments):

```
html
  $gradient: top, red, salmon
  +background(linear-gradient($gradient...))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html
  $gradient: linear-gradient(top, red, salmon)
  +background($gradient)
```

This works for what I'm trying to do, but it's not ideal or very DRY if I needed a mixin to always be a linear gradient.

Comment: This solves my specific issue, but not the problem I was able to boil it down to. I'm not going to mark this answered and I am still looking for more feedback.